# How to flatmap nested lists in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a RDD in spark which looks like this -

```
[Foo1, Bar[bar1,bar2]]
```

The Bar object has a getList method which may return the lists [bar11,bar12,bar13] and [bar21, bar22] respectively. I want the output to look like this -

```
[Foo1, [bar11, bar12, bar13, bar21, bar22]]
```

The approach that I am able to think of is something like this -

```
my_rdd.map(x => (x._1,x._2.getList))
    .flatmap{
        case(x,y) => y.map(x, _)
    }
```

The first map operation is returning me Foo1 and all the lists. However I am not able to flatten them beyond that.

Answer (score 1):

In your code the **x._2.getList**  returns a list of lists. Use flatten method as follows to have the expected result :
my_rdd.map(x => (x._1,x._2.getList.flatten))

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with one line:

```
my_rdd.mapValues(_.flatMap(_.getList))
```

There is another answer which uses `map` instead of `mapValues`.  While this produces the same RDD elements, I think it's important to get in the practice of using the "minimal" function necessary with Spark RDDs, because you can actually pay a pretty huge performance cost for using `map` instead of `mapValues` without realizing it -- The `map` function on RDD strips the partitioner, if it exists, and `mapValues` does not.

If you have an `RDD[(K, V)]` and call `rdd.groupByKey()`, you'll end up with an `RDD[(K, Array[V])]` that is partitioned by `K`.  If you want to `join` with another RDD by `K`, you've already done most of the work.

If you add a `map` in between the `groupByKey()` and `join`, Spark will re-shuffle that RDD.  This is very painful!  `mapValues` is safe.